# Using JavaScript with Adobe PDF Action Wizard to modify tags

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am attempting to modify some tags in a PDF document by using the Action Wizard and creating a new JavaScript action.

My eventual goal is to find all tables and keep the inner tags, but remove the table tags (table, tr, td).

I am not sure if it is even possible to do this or not.

For now, just to test to see if I could find all of the table tags (and get the number), I tried this, but it isn't working:

```
var tables = app.document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var numTables = tables.length;
app.alert(numTables);
```

If this isn't possible, do you have any other suggestions to modify the tags in a PDF document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using JavaScript. The Acrobat JavaScript API does not have access to the structure tags in a PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is unfortunate. Any other potential non-javascript options?

Comment: Yes... you'd have complete access to the PDF structure by writing an Acrobat Plugin in C++ and then exposing the plugin to the Acrobat JavaScript engine. You could then use an Action to trigger the Plugin methods. However, writing an Acrobat plugin is non-trivial. You might want to also consider one of the many PDF library tools that are out there. The Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit, PDFBox, and iText are all deep enough to be used to dig into the structure tags.